# Updating a directives scope using $watch then having ng-repeat use this updated data everytime it's updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to update the scope variable in a a $watch call and then when this is updated have it reflect into ng-repeat so everytime it's updated ng-repeat updates.

Here is a plunker of all the code.
https://plnkr.co/edit/LB8CCvtEZG76D8plMgu6?p=preview

```
link: function($scope, $el,$attrs) {
        $scope.$watch(function(scope){
            return PlayerlistS.getList();
        },
        function (newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log("CHANGED");

            /*I want this to contain the new array and then the ng-repeat must update with the new values.*/
            $scope.players = newVal;
        }, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case you don't even need $watch. You've misspelled factory name in directive, by having that array inside service & call it in a controller then it'll automatically updated. so your directives code can be

```
app.directive("player", ['PlayerListS', function (PlayerListS) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            person:'@person',
            add:'&add'
        },
        replace: false,
        templateUrl: "player.html",
        controller: function($scope, $element, $compile) {
              $scope.add = function(name) {
                  PlayerListS.addToList(name);
                  var get = PlayerListS.getList();
                  $scope.newName = "";
                  console.log(get);
              }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Then in controller you can have `$scope.players = PlayerListS.getList();` and just have that array inside your factory. Here's working plunker version of your requirement: https://plnkr.co/edit/BJofKoeIplaNjoy3k5TW?p=preview